# How to split a string into tokens in C?

Tags: c, split, token

How to split a string into tokens by `'&'` in C?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266357/tokenizing-strings-in-c

Comment: Looks like that question is about splitting a literal string (although the question is low on  details, saying "doesn't work").  This may or may not be what the OP wants.  We should give him a chance to explain that.  Is the string being split a literal string, or is it read-only?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[strtok / strtok_r](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok.html)

```
char *token;
char *state;

for (token = strtok_r(input, "&", &state);
     token != NULL;
     token = strtok_r(NULL, "&", &state))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I would do it something like this (using [`strchr()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strchr.html)):

```
#include <string.h>

char *data = "this&&that&other";
char *next;
char *curr = data;
while ((next = strchr(curr, '&')) != NULL) {
    /* process curr to next-1 */
    curr = next + 1;
}
/* process the remaining string (the last token) */
```

`strchr(const char *s, int c)` returns a pointer to the next location of `c` in `s`, or `NULL` if `c` isn't found in `s`.

You might be able to use `strtok()`, however, I don't like `strtok()`, because:

- it modifies the string being tokenized, so it doesn't work for literal strings, or is not very useful when you want to keep the string for other purposes.  In that case, you must copy the string to a temporary first.
- it merges adjacent delimiters, so if your string was `"a&&b&c"`, the returned tokens are `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"`.  Note that there is no empty token after `"a"`.
- it is not thread-safe.

Comment: I suppose it also depends on the C implementation. On my system the string itself is not modified when I call strtok(). Actually I do not even see how it could. After all it just has to produce pointers to the start of the different tokens within the string.

Comment: Cees Meijer: `strtok()` *does* modify the argument string - the delimiter characters are replaced by '\0', so that the strings returned are properly terminated.

Comment: `strtok` *has* to modify the string if it has to be standards compliant.  From the C standard: *If such a character is found, it is overwritten by a null character, which terminates the current token*.  This is very explicit.  http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok.html.  Can you post code where `strtok()` doesn't modify the string?

Comment: Oops. I suppose you must be right. My mistake. Indeed changing the delimiter to \0 is the only way it could work. And after closer examination of my code (it's an embedded system so inspecting the disassembled code was not that hard) I see this is exactly what happens.

Comment: I don't understand how this is going to split the string by `&`. For example, how could you get the first token, `this`, by itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the strok() function as shown in the example below.

```
/// Function to parse a string in separate tokens 

int parse_string(char pInputString[MAX_STRING_LENGTH],char *Delimiter,
                   char *pToken[MAX_TOKENS])
{
  int i;
  i = 0;

  pToken[i] = strtok(pInputString, Delimiter);
  i++;

  while ((pToken[i] = strtok(NULL, Delimiter)) != NULL){
     i++;
  }
  return i;
}

/// The array pTokens[] now contains the pointers to the start of each token in the (unchanged) original string.

sprintf(String,"Token1&Token2");
NrOfParameters = parse_string(String,"&",pTokens);

sprintf("%s, %s",pToken[0],pToken[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, using `strtok()` function is unintuitive and too complicated, so I managed to create my own one. As arguments it accepts a string to split, character which determinates spaces between tokens and pointer representing number of found tokens (useful when printing these tokens in loop). A disadvantage of this function is fixed maximum lenght of each token.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 32


char **txtspt(const char *text, char split_char, int *w_count)
{
    if(strlen(text) <= 1) 
        return NULL;

    char **cpy0 = NULL;
    int i, j = 0, k = 0, words = 1;

    //Words counting
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(text); ++i)
    {
        if(text[i] == split_char && text[i + 1] != '\0')
        {
            ++words;
        }
    }
    //Memory reservation
    cpy0 = (char **) malloc(strlen(text) * words);
    for(i = 0; i < words; ++i)
    {
        cpy0[i] = (char *) malloc(MAX_WORD_LEN);
    }

    //Splitting
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(text) + 1; ++i)
    {
       if(text[i] == split_char)
       {
           cpy0[k++][j] = '\0';
           j = 0;
       }
       else
       {
           if(text[i] != '\n')           //Helpful, when using fgets() 
                cpy0[k][j++] = text[i];  //function
       }

    }

    *w_count = words;
    return cpy0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:

```
char str[] = "&a&&b&c"; // a mutable string

for (char *cp = str; (cp = strtok(cp, "&")) != NULL; cp = NULL) {
    /* do something with the token */
}
```

There's a **single** call to `strtok()`, a **single** instance of the delimiter string, and the scope of `cp` is contained within this loop.

The suggestion to use `strchr()` doesn't account for multiple delimiter characters. It might have been better had it suggested `strcspn()`. And, notice that the last token has to be handled AFTER the loop has finished. Not a great design...

An advantage of `strtok()` is that the tokens have been isolated in their current location. If their addresses are preserved in an array of pointers, they can be used repeatedly without isolating them over and over again.

Comment: Whether `&a&&b&c` should be split into 3 parts as `strtok()` (or better `strtok_r()`) will or 5 parts including 2 empty strings as `strchr()` will allow depends is a question of specification.  The question is quite vague to this regard: the method `split` available in other languages suggests the latler rather than the former, while `tokens` suggests the former.  The OP undoubtedly knows better by now, more than 12 years later.  An alternative using `strtok_r` with the same *good* properties seems preferable albeit non-standard.

Comment: @chqrlie Your point, "3 or 5 tokens", is valid, and the OP didn't specify... The `strchr()` answer here has some problems. And, the "double strtok()" answer has its problems problems (if you see what I mean :-)... Came across this question and thought I'd toss in my preferred version... And, sadly, I don't have `strtok_r()`... Maybe that's a project for the weekend!! `:-)`

Comment: ```#include <string.h>

char *strtok_r(char *s, const char *delim, char **context) {
    char *token = NULL;

    if (s == NULL)
        s = *context;

    /* skip initial delimiters */
    s += strspn(s, delim);
    if (*s != '\0') {
        /* we have a token */
        token = s;
        /* skip the token */
        s += strcspn(s, delim);
        if (*s != '\0') {
            /* cut the string to terminate the token */
            *s++ = '\0';
        }
    }
    *context = s;
    return token;
}```

Comment: @chqrlie Okay! Thanks... Guess I'll have to wash the car instead... Thanks a lot! `:-)`

Comment: Or come to Paris and have a glass of wine :)