# sscanf with "_" delimiter in C

Tags: c

I'm running the following code in C. I'm not getting the right answer.

```
int main()
{

    char test[100] = "This_Is_A_Test_99";
    char tmp1[10],tmp2[10],tmp3[10],tmp4[10],tmp5[10];

    sscanf(test,"%[^'_'],%[^'_'],%[^'_'],%[^'_'],%s",tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4,tmp5);

    printf ("Temp 1 is %s\n",tmp1);
    printf ("Temp 2 is %s\n",tmp2);
    printf ("Temp 3 is %s\n",tmp3);
    printf ("Temp 4 is %s\n",tmp4);
    printf ("Temp 5 is %s\n",tmp5);

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is

```
Temp 1 is This
Temp 2 is 
Temp 3 is 
Temp 4 is 
Temp 5 is
```

What is that I have to do fetch "This" "Is" "A" "Test" and "99" on individual variables.

Comment: Offtopic but `%[^'_']` looked like a cute clockwork robot face! And you have four of them assembled in a line.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
sscanf(test,"%[^'_'],%[^'_'],%[^'_'],%[^'_'],%s",tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4,tmp5);
```

should be

```
sscanf(test,"%[^_]_%[^_]_%[^_]_%[^_]_%s",tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4,tmp5);
```

Note that you are separating the placeholders with `,` instead of `_`.

See http://ideone.com/8zBmG.

Also, you don't need the `'`s unless you want to skip the single quotes as well.

(BTW, you should take a look into [`strtok_r`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091815/how-to-split-string-to-tokens-in-c).)

Comment: Shouldn't all specifiers have `s` at the end ?

Comment: @cnicutar: [No](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html).

Comment: +1, but it's better be safe about arrays lenghts, and I'd test the return value: `if (sscanf(test, "%9[^_]_%9[^_]_%9[^_]_%9[^_]_%9s", tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, tmp4, tmp5) != 5) /* handle error */;`

Answer (score 5):

You are scanning commata between your strings, and there are none in the text. Remove them from the pattern:

```
sscanf(test,"%[^'_']%[^'_']%[^'_']%[^'_']%s",tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4,tmp5);
```

Apostrophes are probably unnecessary, too. You don't need to quote anything since no shell is going to expand it:

```
sscanf(test,"%[^_]%[^_]%[^_]%[^_]%s",tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4,tmp5);
```

Taking up pmg's suggestion, you should write the length of your temporary explicitly into the scanf arguments to make sure you don't get buffer overflows:

```
sscanf(test,"%9[^_]%9[^_]%9[^_]%9[^_]%9s",tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4,tmp5);
```

And then check the return value:

```
int token_count = sscanf(test,"%9[^_]%9[^_]%9[^_]%9[^_]%9s",tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4,tmp5);
if ( token_count != 5 ) { fprintf(stderr, "Something went wrong\n"); exit(42); }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you have included commas (,) in your `sscanf` string.

But there are no commas in your input.  Without any commas to process, `sscanf` is failing after the first string `"This"`

I recommend trying the format string:

```
"%[^_]_%[^_]_%[^_]_%[^_]_%s"
```

Comment: Nor anything to match the underscores (haven't used `scanf` in a long time, but that looks odd to me).

Comment: @Kitcha:  You should really start accepting the answers that help you out the most.  Please check the "CheckMark" next to the answer that is best for each of your 7 questions.