# I have a filename ABCD_81018293.txt. I try sscanf to get ABCD as text and the digits as an int

Tags: c

One of the many forms I have tried is

```
    char *text, ebuf[32];
    int *num;     
    strncpy (ebuf,tfp->d_name,strlen(tfp->d_name));
    sscanf (ebuf, "%s_%i.txt", text, num);
```

### I started originally with tfp->d_name in place of the ebuf hack, with the same results: segment faults. I understood from the man page that perhaps the %s should be %4c (text string has 4 characters - but not always). Anyway %4c or 4%c didn't make any difference.

Thanks to all who responded. Your clarifications - especially WhozCraig's "better man page" - put me on the right track.

The initialization issue was not my major problem, it was the syntax of the sscanf. For my program, once initialization was out of the way, the single line I really needed was:

```
      sscanf (tfp->d_name, "%[^_]_%i", &text[0], &num);
```

Comment: Fyi, likely [a much better man page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: `text` is a pointer to......nothing. You must create something to point to: using [malloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html) or a static array. The same for `num`.

Comment: `text` points to a random block of memory, which scanf will attempt to overwrite

Comment: `char text[sizeof ebuf]; int num;` ... `sscanf(ebuf, "%[^_]_%i.", text, &num);`

Comment: There are many issues: one of them : `strncpy (ebuf,tfp->d_name,strlen(tfp->d_name));` -> `strncpy (ebuf,tfp->d_name,strlen(tfp->d_name) + 1);`, otherwise you won't copy the terminating NUL character. But BTW you don't need to copy the `tfp->d_name` string to `ebuf`, you can directly scan from `tfp->d_name`.

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer are not inizialize, so are pointing to nothing consistent.

You can allocate space for them using malloc, like:

```
char *text = malloc(max_len);
int *num = malloc(sizeof(int));
// ....
free(text);
free(num);
```

As you can see `malloc`ated memory must be `free`d to release the allocated memory.

Otherwise you can use a simple variable and an array to store your [c-string](/questions/tagged/c-string)

```
char text[max_len];
int num;
// ...
sscanf (ebuf, "%s_%i.txt", text, &num);
```

Take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141208/sscanf-with-delimiter-in-c) to understand how you can manage to trigger a '_' as string delimiter.
So, as BLUEPIXY commented you:

```
sscanf(ebuf, "%[^_]_%i.", text, &num);
```

Last thing, you can avoid the `strncpy`, and `sscanf` directly to `tfp->d_name`

```
sscanf(tfp->d_name, "%[^_]_%i.", text, &num);
```

This also avoid the "explosion" of `sscanf` due to the no null terminated `ebuf` string: You should use `strlen(tfp->d_name)+1` as third parameter of your `strncpy` to copy to `ebuf` the null terminator too.

As [strlen Man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html) says:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The strlen() function calculates the length of the string pointed to
>          by s, ***excluding the terminating null byte ('\0')***.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>