# Extract (possibly empty) words from string using sscanf (separated by "|")

Tags: c

I want to extract words from string.

I dont want to use `strtok` because it will spoil my source string. Another thing is that I am wondering if it is possible to manage to do what I want without using cycles.

Here is my code sample. It successfully reads first word but second and third remain empty.

```
char source[] = "XXX|YYY|ZZZ";

char word1[10] = "";
char word2[10] = "";
char word3[10] = "";

sscanf( source, "%[^|]s|%[^|]s|%s", word1, word2, word3 );
```

Is it really possible to do it using `sscanf` or I am on the wrong path?

**UPDATE:**

It looks like user3121023's answer does not work for empty words.

```
char source[] = "XXX||ZZZ";

char word1[10] = "";
char word2[10] = "";
char word3[10] = "";

sscanf( source, "%[^|]|%[^|]|%s", word1, word2, word3 );
```

Third word remains empty. What should I do in this situaltion?

Comment: @user3121023: Thank you! It works!

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre: you are right - but I spent hour trying to find answer to my question in the internet and it just did not show up.

Comment: note: this was closed as duplicate of "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141208/sscanf-with-delimiter-in-c" but here there's the "empty word" constraint. So I reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sscanf()` format does not empty substrings, neither does it protect against potential buffer overflows if the target arrays are smaller than the source string.

Here is a solution with `strcspn()` and a utility function `strcpy_n`:

```
#include <string.h>

char *strcpy_n(char *dest, size_t size, const char *src, size_t n) {
    if (size > 0) {
        if (n >= size)
            n = size - 1;
        memcpy(dest, src, n);
        dest[n] = '\0';
    }
    return dest;
}

...

    char source[] = "XXX||ZZZ";
    char word1[10], word2[10], word3[10] = "";

    size_t pos = 0, len;

    len = strcspn(source + pos, "|");
    strcpy_n(word1, sizeof(word1), source + pos, len);
    pos = pos + len + (source[pos + len] == '|');

    len = strcspn(source + pos, "|");
    strcpy_n(word2, sizeof(word2), source + pos, len);
    pos = pos + len + (source[pos + len] == '|');

    len = strcspn(source + pos, "|");
    strcpy_n(word3, sizeof(word3), source + pos, len);
    pos = pos + len + (source[pos + len] == '|');

...
```

You can wrap the above code into another utility function `getfield()` to factor more code:

```
/* returns non zero if there are more fields to parse */
int getfield(char *dest, size_t size, const char *source, size_t *ppos) {
    int has_separator = 0;
    size_t pos = *ppos;
    size_t len = strcspn(source + pos, "|");
    strcpy_n(dest, size, source + pos, len);
    pos += len;
    has_separator = (source[pos] == '|');
    *ppos = pos + has_separator;
    return has_separator;
}

 ...

    char source[] = "XXX||ZZZ";
    char word1[10], word2[10], word3[10];

    size_t pos = 0;

    /* parse the fields, empty and missing fields are set to "" */
    getfield(word1, sizeof(word1), source, &pos);
    getfield(word2, sizeof(word2), source, &pos);
    getfield(word3, sizeof(word3), source, &pos);

...
```

Comment: Thank you. That is a very accurate solution.