# Split string based on separating character

Tags: c

How can I split a string into an array of strings based on a dividing character? For instance, how could I split a sentence into an array of words, separated by the space character?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to split string to tokens in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091815/how-to-split-string-to-tokens-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use either `strtok` or `strtok_r`, both of which are described [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strtok.html) (with examples).  I'd recommended to use `strtok_r`, since `strtok` is thread-unsafe, and you may add threads to your application in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = strtok( str, delims );
while( result != NULL ) {
    printf( "result is \"%s\"\n", result );
    result = strtok( NULL, delims );
}
```

Set delims as your delimiter