# How do I store an array in three different ones based on delimiters

Tags: c

I want to split an input array into three different ones based on a `/` as a delimiter.

I have tried the (probably the naive) approach of storing an input string into different arrays by using `getchar` and `while` to read in the characters into an array and using a counter to count how many times a `/` appears.

Based on this number I would use:

```
if (slashcounter == 0) {
      destinationarray[i++] = c;
}
```

to store it into the proper array. full implementation below.

please note that I try to do this using only `stdio.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>

char c; 
char replace[80], toBeReplaced[80], input[80], testInput[80];
int i = 0;
int slashcounter = 0;

int main(){

    puts("Enter a line of text: ");

    while (( c = getchar()) != '\n'){

        if (c == '/') {
            slashcounter++;
        }

        if (slashcounter == 0) {
            replace[i++] = c;
        }

        else if (slashcounter == 1) {
            toBeReplaced[i++] = c;
        }

        else if (slashcounter == 2) {
            input[i++] = c;
        }


    }
    //debug purpose
    puts("The arrays have the following content\n");
    puts("replace[]:\n");
    puts(replace);
    puts("\n");
    puts("toBeReplaced[]:\n");
    puts(toBeReplaced);
    puts("\n");
    puts("input[]:\n");
    puts(input);
    printf("Slashcounter = %d\n",slashcounter);



    return 0;
```

Unfortunately, what happens is: that the first word i.e. the word before the first slash is stored correctly but the other two are empty.

What have I done wrong here

the current output with the input `this/test/fails`

```
Enter a line of text: 
this/test/fails
The arrays have the following content

replace[]:

this


toBeReplaced[]:




input[]:


Slashcounter = 2
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

p.s. I would also like to ensure that the `/`s are not in the output array.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function.

Comment: As for your current program, I recommend that you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Pay close attention to the variable `i` and its values. And don't forget that `char` strings are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*.

Comment: I managed it with strtok but this is found in `string.h` and I am only allowed to use stdio.h and the functions getchar(), puts() and putchar()

Comment: [strtok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091815/how-to-split-a-string-into-tokens-in-c) should be user, but its from `string.h`, do handle that manually, you will need `to read input string by char` and `found each position of delimiter` and then `split to tokens` (from 0 index to first occur, from  'firstOccur+1' index to second, etc..

Comment: `char c;` needs to be `int`. `getchar()` unintuitively returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two immediate problems in your code, first you miss to add a null character to end each sub string, second you never reset the index to 0 when you read a /

Other problems are you do not check if you will write out of the arrays, and you do not not manages the EOF

You also test the value of *slashcounter* all the time, this is quite expensive for nothing, you can have 3 loops or use a pointer to point to the array to fill etc

There is also no reason to use global variables, all of them can be local in *main*

Example with minimal changes :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int c;
  char replace[80], toBeReplaced[80], input[80];
  int i = 0;
  int slashcounter = 0;

  puts("Enter a line of text: ");

  while (( c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    if (c == EOF) {
      fprintf(stderr, "unexpected EOF");
      return -1;
    }

    if (c == '/') {
      if (slashcounter == 0) {
        replace[i] = 0;
      }
      else if (slashcounter == 1) {
        toBeReplaced[i] = 0;
      }
      else if (slashcounter == 2) {
        input[i] = c;
      }
      i = 0;
      slashcounter++;
    }
    else if (slashcounter == 0) {
      if (i != (sizeof(replace) - 2))
        replace[i++] = c;
    }
    else if (slashcounter == 1) {
      if (i != (sizeof(toBeReplaced) - 2))
        toBeReplaced[i++] = c;
    }
    else if (slashcounter == 2) {
      if (i != (sizeof(input) - 2))
        input[i++] = c;
    }
  }

  if (slashcounter == 0) {
    replace[i] = 0;
    toBeReplaced[0] = 0;
    input[0] = 0;
  }
  else if (slashcounter == 1) {
    toBeReplaced[i] = 0;
    input[0] = 0;
  }
  else if (slashcounter == 2) {
    input[i] = 0;
  }

  //debug purpose
  puts("The arrays have the following content\n");
  puts("replace[]:\n");
  puts(replace);
  puts("\n");
  puts("toBeReplaced[]:\n");
  puts(toBeReplaced);
  puts("\n");
  puts("input[]:\n");
  puts(input);
  printf("Slashcounter = %d\n",slashcounter);

  return 0;
}
```

Note I use an *int* for *c* to handle *EOF* and I removed the useless array *testInput*

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter a line of text: 
this/test/fails
The arrays have the following content

replace[]:

this


toBeReplaced[]:

test


input[]:

fails
Slashcounter = 2
```