# What's gone wrong with the values in this struct?

Tags: c, struct

Relatively new to `C` and will readily concede there are things I think I understand, but probably don't appreciate all the nuances. This is a MWE extracted from a more involved program I wrote.  It compiles and runs fine, but testing reveals that the value of `ev->pin` is initially correct, but is incorrect after an unrelated function call (look for ??? in the code)  Looks like the memory is getting stomped on somehow, but I cannot figure out what is going on.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SCAN_EVENT_COUNT 5
#define PIN_ASSIGNMENTS {7, -1, 1, 13, 4}
#define EVENT_NAMES "first-second-third-fourth-fifth"

void init_scan_events();
int parse_string(char pInputString[],
                 char *Delimiter,
                 char *pToken[]);

struct scan_events
{
  char event_names[31];
  char *pEvent[SCAN_EVENT_COUNT];
  int pin[SCAN_EVENT_COUNT];
};

int main(void)
{
  init_scan_events();
  return (0);
}

/**
 * the following function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091906/633251
 * Note that `strtok` expects a `char * string` and `char * delimiter` as arguments.
 **/

int parse_string(char pInputString[],
                 char *Delimiter,
                 char *pToken[])
{
  int i = 0;
  pToken[i] = strtok(pInputString, Delimiter); // get first token
  i++;
  while ((pToken[i] = strtok(NULL, Delimiter)) != NULL) // get the rest of the tokens
  {
    i++;
  }
  return i;
}

void init_scan_events()
{
  char en[] = EVENT_NAMES;
  int en_size = strlen(en);
  int size = SCAN_EVENT_COUNT;
  int pin[] = PIN_ASSIGNMENTS;

  int token_count = 0;
  char *Delim = "-";
  int i;

  struct scan_events *ev = malloc(sizeof(struct scan_events));
  if (ev == NULL)
  {
    printf("Allocation failed\n");
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < en_size; i++) // copy EVENT_NAMES
  {
    ev->event_names[i] = en[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) // copy PIN_ASSIGNMENTS
  {
    ev->pin[i] = pin[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    printf("% d ", ev->pin[i]); // ??? inspect pin values: correct!
  }
  printf("\n");

  token_count = parse_string(ev->event_names, Delim, ev->pEvent); // tokenize EVENT_NAMES

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    printf("% d ", ev->pin[i]); // ??? check pin values: corrupted!
  }
  printf("\n");

  free(ev);
}
```

Comment: gdb's watch breakpoint is the tool of choice to track that down.

Comment: You should rid of the `int i` as it's being shodowed.

Comment: @AllanWind What does "shadowed" mean?

Comment: It means your loop variable `for(int i` is using the same name as the outer `int i` so the outer value is not accessible within the loop.  This is usually a bug; in this case minor issue that outer variable is not used.

Comment: @AllanWind OK, thank you,  I understand.  That's not the source of the problem though.

Comment: The first thing I'd look at is the size of your arrays. Specifically the `event_names[31]` field, you might not be counting the terminating '\0' (that's common). Use `sizeof()` to get the size of a string (both when looping, and in the declaration), `strlen()` doesn't count the '\0'.

Comment: @JohnBayko Thanks John, that's good to know.  In the more complex actual version `event_names` length is computed from user input but I may need to add one to the length.

Comment: @BryanHanson Definitely looks like you're not copying the terminal '\0', so `strtok()` is scanning past the end and into your struct, and changing any 45 (ASCII '-') byte into 0, because you don't tell the loop to stop at 5 (it's good practice to add the destination array length as a parameter to always stop, don't depend on the input being correct).

Comment: @JohnBayko Great explanation and advice.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's a buffer overflow  in `parse_string()` for the assignment `pToken[5] = NULL`.  I suggest pass in SCAN_EVENT_COUNT and use that to limit `i < 5`.
2. `ev->event_names` may not be '\0' terminated which would trigger undefined behavior in `strtok()` which expects a string.  Either run the loop to `<= en_size` or use `strcpy()`.
3. sizeof EVENT_NAMES == 32 so `char event_names[31]` is not big enough.  Don't repeat stuff.  In this case is the projection `strlen(EVENT_NAMES) == 31` so it should be `strlen(EVENT_NAMES) + 1` or as you have array just use `sizeof`.
4. If malloc fail you can't use `ev`.  It's not unreasonable to `exit(1)` as you probably can't do anything about it anyways.
5. Optimized `init_scan_events()` (away) to focus on the above issues.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DELIM "-"
#define SCAN_EVENT_COUNT 5
#define PIN_ASSIGNMENTS (int []) {7, -1, 1, 13, 4}
#define EVENT_NAMES "first-second-third-fourth-fifth"

struct scan_events {
    char event_names[sizeof EVENT_NAMES];
    char *pEvent[SCAN_EVENT_COUNT];
    int pin[SCAN_EVENT_COUNT];
};

int parse_string(char pInputString[], const char *Delimiter, size_t n, char *pToken[]);
void print(struct scan_events *ev);

int parse_string(char pInputString[], const char *Delimiter, size_t n, char *pToken[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < n; i++) {
        pToken[i] = strtok(i ? NULL : pInputString, Delimiter); // get first token
        if(!pToken[i]) break;
    }
    return i;
}

void print(struct scan_events *ev) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SCAN_EVENT_COUNT; i++)
        printf("% d%c", ev->pin[i], i + 1 < SCAN_EVENT_COUNT ? ' ' : '\n');
}

int main(void) {
    struct scan_events ev;
    strcpy(ev.event_names, EVENT_NAMES);
    memcpy(ev.pin, PIN_ASSIGNMENTS, sizeof PIN_ASSIGNMENTS);
    print(&ev);
    parse_string(ev.event_names, DELIM, SCAN_EVENT_COUNT, ev.pEvent);
    print(&ev);
}
```

and example run:

```
 7 -1  1  13  4 
 7 -1  1  13  4
```

Comment: `ev->event_names[]` comes from `malloc()` and is not a string. `strtok()` only works as UB... There may or may not be a NUL at the end of the buffer.

Comment: Thank you.  My nascent feeling was it was some kind of overrun since there wasn't a seg fault, but I wasn't looking at that function since it had worked fine in other testing.

Comment: @Fe2O3 "UB" -- what's that mean?

Comment: Undefined behavior.  If you have a char * array and pass that to a function that expects a string (i.e. `\0` terminated) then bad things can happen.  I am still trying to understand what @Fe2O3 is getting at...

Comment: Use strcpy: In testing my method does get `event_names` into the struct properly.  Is strcpy a more native `C` way to do it?

Comment: @Fe2O3's point is that  `ev->event_names[i] = en[i]` doesn't copy the trailing '\0'.  Either use <= en_size or use `strcpy()` instead.

Comment: Personally, I'd ditch the long string literal, directly initialising the array of ptrs to the chosen strings: `char *strs[] = { "first", "second", ...`... If needed, bulk copy that array of (local?) ptrs to the allocated array... Why invoke `strtok()` unnecessarily?

Comment: Other than your loop being off by 1 it's fine to what you did.  `strcpy()` is highly optimized and shorter to write.

Comment: `strcpy()` copies the entire string, but doesn't check that the destination buffer is large enough. If you know it is, go ahead. `strncpy()` checks the buffer size, but might not copy the whole string (could also skip the '\0'). Strings in C are problematic at best, assume they are out to trick you. Look up `snprintf()`, it's sadly usually the safest standard, or `strlcpy()` if it's available.

Comment: @JohnBayko Many parts of `C` seem "out to trick" me!  But I'm improving...

Comment: @BryanHanson Agreed, you can sneeze and result in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: `sizeof(scan_events.event_names)` - nope. `sizeof(((scan_events){0}).event_names)` - OK. ?!

Comment: Beware of `strtok()` gotchas.  `strtok()` modifies the input string (so I prefer `strpbrk()`).  The tokens point into the input string so if you ever modify that string your tokens are invalid.

Comment: @JohnBayko I think you mean `sizeof ((struct scan_events *) 0)->event_names`.

Comment: @AllanWind Both work.