# want to separate string in to tokens using specific character

Tags: c, strtok

Here i have one string means character array. this array contains separator character also. Now i want to take out only strings without this separator.

I am using `strtok` function.

I want to separate all my words with this separator.

But here i am getting some problems in this code.

Please Let me know if i am doing something wrong or tell me different way simple and easy way to achieve this thing,consider memory risk also.

Here this line `pch = strtok (str,&sep);` get nothing. Problem is here only.

Code

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SEPRATOR 0x03

int main ()
{
    char str[1024];
    int count = 0;
    char sep;
    memset(str,0,1024);
    sep = SEPRATOR;

    memcpy(str,"1",strlen("1"));
    count = count + strlen("1");
    str[count++] = sep;
    memcpy(str+count,"0",strlen("0"));
    count = count + strlen("0");
    str[count++] = sep;
    memcpy(str+count,"2",strlen("2"));
    count = count + strlen("2");
    str[count++] = sep;
    memcpy(str+count,"abc_1.0.xyz",strlen("abc_1.0.xyz"));
    count = count + strlen("abc_1.0.xyz");
    str[count++] = sep;
    memcpy(str+count,"3",strlen("3"));
    count = count + strlen("3");
    str[count++] = sep;
    memcpy(str+count,"23455.456",strlen("23455.456"));
    count = count + strlen("23455.456");

    printf("Input String = %s\n",str);

    char * pch;
    int pchcount = 0;
    pch = strtok (str,&sep);
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        pchcount++;
        printf ("%d === %s\n",pchcount,pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL,&sep);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chris The question you suggested is for [tag:C++]. This question is tagged as [tag:C]. However, this question is a possible duplicate of [Tokenizing strings in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266357/tokenizing-strings-in-c).

Comment: @EitanT, My bad, it was tagged C++ when I went looking for the FAQ one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to `strtok()` is a null terminated string (`char*`), but you passing the address of a single `char`. While a `char*`, it will not be null terminated. Change to:

```
char sep[2] = { SEPRATOR, 0 };
```

Changing current uses of `sep` accordingly:

```
str[count++] = sep[0];

pch = strtok(str, sep);
```

You may find `snprintf()` simpler to construct your `str` than the sequence of `memcpy()` invocations.

Also, if you want to initialise `str`:

```
char str[1024] = ""; /* instead of performing a memset(). */
```

Comment: So how can i do this? What is the solution

Comment: thanks for Your response. Its necessary to free pch pointer which i used in my code? Because i have to take care of memory issue also.

Comment: @hmjd Can you please explain me Why we dnt require to free pch pointer. Because i have also confusion about this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @user1089679, `strtok()` iterates over the buffer passed to it. The return value from `strtok()` is referring to different locations within that buffer, it performs no `malloc()`.