# c, delete words which contain digits from a string

Tags: c, string

I need to delete all words that contain digits from the string.

E.g. if input is `abdgh 67fgh 32ghj hj dfg43 11 fg`, output should be `abdgh hj fg`.

I thought of using `while( text[i] != ' ')`, but I don't know how to continue it for the rest of the string (after the first whitespace).

I don't have any other idea, and couldn't find anything by googling. Please, help me!

Comment: You could parse your strings using delimiters.

Comment: A good start might be to split the input line into "words", separated by space.

Comment: And then check in each word character by character whether it's a digit. If so, just go to the next word without saving the current one. This could be at least your first idea.

Comment: Take a look at using `strtok`, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266357/tokenizing-strings-in-c
Once you can tokenize, you can just not output any words with digits.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I'm a beginner in programming, and I'm not quiet sure how to do that. Could you, please, explane in more details. Thanks

Comment: I would personally tokenize it into individual elements in a linked list and just remove any element which has a digit in it using isdigit(), then reconstruct a new string with what's left over. If you want to use that method, I'll leave the implementation up to you

Comment: Split the input into words separated by spaces -possibly using `strtok`, and then choose a function `has_digit` and use it to exclude words with digits.

Comment: You might want to read about the [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) and [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) functions.

Comment: @Filipe Gonçalves how to split the input without     strtok? I'm a student, and we've not covered it yet, so I'm not sure whether we can use it.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to split the string, you could always use array notation to left-shift everything over the top of portions of the string containing words with digits. That would be a terrible thing to do, in terms of processing time and optimization (O(2^n) if I'm not mistaken), but in a program as small as yours it wouldn't really matter. Keep in mind, though, that a lot of instructors teach students by forcing the students to do independent research in order to find a good method on their own.

Answer (score 0):

Here, i gave it a try. Works just fine for me. I tried to explain the logic throughout the code via comments. Hope it helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int containsNum(char * str);

int main()
{

  char  str[] = "abdgh 67fgh 32ghj hj dfg43 11 fg"; // input string

  char newstr[100] = ""; //new string to create with filtered data

  char * pch; //temp string to use in strtok

  printf("given string : %s\n",str    );

  pch = strtok (str," ");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    if(!containsNum(pch))// creation of new string  with strcat
    {                    // if the current word not contains any number
        strcat(newstr,pch);
        strcat(newstr," ");  //adding a space between words for readability
    }
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }

    printf("modified string : %s\n", newstr );

   return 0;
}
//function containsNum
//gets a string and checks if it has any numbers in it
//returns 1 if so , 0 otherwise
int containsNum(char * str)
{
    int i,
        size =strlen(str),
        flag=0;
    for(i=0; i<size ; ++i)
    {
        if((int)str[i] >=48 && (int)str[i] <=57 ){
           flag =1;
           break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Regards

Comment: I'm sure the student (OP) appreciates you doing his homework for him.

Comment: @Alegria Thanks a lot) But it prints some garbage before newstr, like this: _я$abdghhjfg_

Comment: Oh, just initialize the newstr as in `char newstr[100] = "";` This should do.

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm:**

1-You will have to break your input string into smaller components which are also called as tokens.  For example: for the string `abdgh 67fgh 32ghj hj dfg43 11 fg` the tokens could be `abdgh`, `67fgh`, `32ghj`, `hj`, `dfg43`, `11` and `fg`.

2- These smaller strings or tokens can be formed using the `strtok` function which is defined as
`char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );`. The`str` in the first argument is the input sting which in the code presented below is `string1`. The second argument called the `delimiters` is what actually defines when to divide the input string into smaller pieces(tokens).
For instance, a `whitespace` as a `delimiter` will divide the `input` string whenever a `whitespace` is encountered, which is how the string is being divided in the code.

3-Since, your program needs to delete those words in the input string which contain digits we can use the `isdigit()` function to check exactly that.

**WORKING CODE:**

```
#include <cstring>
#include <ctype.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
 char output[100]=""; 
 int counter;
 int check=0; /* An integer variable which takes the value of "1" whenever a digit 
         is encountered in one of the smaller strings or tokens.
         So, whenever check is 1 for any of the tokens that token is to be ignored, that is, 
         not shown in the output string.*/

 char string1[] = "abdgh 67fgh 32ghj hj dfg43 11 fg";

 char delimiters[] = " ";//A whitespace character functions as a delimiter in the program

 char * token;//Tokens are the sub-strings or the smaller strings which are part of the input string.

 token=strtok(string1,delimiters);/*The first strktok call forms the first token/substring which for the input
                             given would be abdgh*/

 while(token!=NULL)/*For the last substring(token) the strtok function call will return a NULL pointer, which
              also indicates the last of the tokens(substrings) that can be formed for a given input string.
              The while loop finishes when the NULL pointer is encountered.*/

 {
 for(counter=0;counter<=strlen(token)-1;counter++)/*This for loop iterates through each token element. 
                                                  Example: In case of abdgh, it will first check for 'a', 
                                                  then 'b', then 'd' and so on..*/


 {
if(isdigit((int)token[counter])>0)/*This is to check if a digit has been encountered inside a token(substring).
                                  If a digit is encountered we make check equal to 1 and break our loop, as
                                  then that token is to be ignored and there is no real need to iterate
                                  through the rest of the elements of the token*/
    {
    check=1;
    break;
    }
    }
if(check==1)    /* Outside the for loop, if check is equal to one that means we have to ignore that token and
                it is not to be made a part of the output string. So we just concatenate(join) an 
                empty string ( represented by " " )with the output string*/
{
    strcat(output,"");  
    check=0;
}
else            /*If a token does not contain any digit we simply make it a part of the output string
                by concatenating(joining) it with the output string. We also add a space for clarity.*/
{
    strcat(output,token);
    strcat(output," ");
}
   token = strtok( NULL, delimiters ); /*This line of code forms a new token(substring) every time it is executed
                                 inside the while loop*/
}
printf( "Output string  is:: %s\n", output ); //Prints the final result

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3331279 Please review the answer above. I have added detailed comments so that the actual code becomes easier to understand.
Unfortunately earlier I had misread the question. Hopefully, this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char *filter(char *str){
    char *p, *r;
    p = r = str;
    while(*r){
        char *prefetch = r;
        bool contain_digit = false;
        while(!isspace(*prefetch) && *prefetch){
            if(contain_digit)
                ++prefetch;
            else if(isdigit(*prefetch++))
                contain_digit = true;
        }
        if(contain_digit){
            r = prefetch;
        }else {
            while(r < prefetch){
                *p++ = *r++;
            }
        }
        if(!*r)
            break;
        if(p[-1] == *r)
            ++r;
        else
            *p++ =*r++;
    }
    *p = '\0';
    return str;
}

int main(void) {
    char text[] = "abdgh 67fgh 32ghj hj dfg43 11 fg";

    printf("%s\n", filter(text));//abdgh hj fg

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a question about C. This code won't compile in a C compiler.

Comment: note : (1) the text does not begin with a space character. (2) Extra space is left when the last deleted word.,

Comment: @ciphermagi ; Please indicate the basis that can not be compiled.