# How to get a specific word from a string and eliminate others in C

Tags: c, string

Hi following is the path of a file (which is stored as a string).

*C:/db/OOSA/LIBRARIES/OOSA00/MS/filename.jpg*

now I want only the file name from that for eg: "*filename*", rest should be filtered or removed.
How to do that in C?
I want to apply that file name to some other stuffs but i want to avoid *.jpg* extension and the path " *C:/db/OOSA/LIBRARIES/OOSA00/MS/*"
Below is the code:

```
   static mgbool gbeadNApply (mgrec* db, mgrec* parent, mgrec* rec, void* gBead)
{
   toolrec* toolRec = (toolrec*)gBead;

   if (mgGetCode(rec) == fltXref);
   {
           char *xName;
           parent = mgGetParent(rec);
           mgGetAttList(rec,fltXrefFilename,&xName,MG_NULL);
           mgSetName(parent,xName);
       }

   return MG_TRUE;
}
```

Here xName first collects the filename including path. and in mgSetName also you can see xName ( here xName assigns the collected file name along with path some thing like *C:/db/OOSA/LIBRARIES/OOSA00/MS/filename.jpg*. Now the thing is I want only the filename part of it to be written to mgSetName. so i want to filter xName for it.

Comment: Find the index of the last `/` in the string. Find the index of the last `.` in the string. Copy the characters between those two.

Comment: You can use strtok in C. Have a look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266357/tokenizing-strings-in-c

Comment: step 1: describe in english how you would get that part. step 2: code it... see, that's what @Paul did.

Comment: strtok is actually quite tricky to use here. Brute force is better :)

Comment: ill post the entire code here n i'll explain what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be very vague, but you can probably figure out how to write a function to do this:

1. Write a function to find the "."
2. Write a function that returns, in a new string, everything before the "."
3. Write a function that finds the last "/" ( backslash? "\")
4. Write a function that removes everything before and including the "/"

you will use `for` loops

```
int find_period(const char *string)
{
  if(!string) return -1;

  int n;
  for(n = 0; n < strlen(string); n++){
    if(string[n] == '.') return n;

    return -1;
}
```

Then you probably get the general idea.

Comment: 1. reinvent the wheel 2. reinvent the wheel 3. reinvent the wheel

Comment: I'd rather locate the last backslash first, as a precaution against extensionless files and directory names containing full stops.

Comment: I am a beginer in C. so dont know where to tweak or add. please someone hep me to achieve this,

Comment: @SarathSankar didn't write the code posted, considering the level of the question asked, and the acceptance of this answer. I suggest you find and follow a string handling tutorial, to accustom you to the available library functions.

Comment: i concur with that statement.