# C Program to search file for numbers greater than 100

Tags: c, file

The objective is to write an int function that returns the number of occurrences of numbers greater than 100 in a text file. The function should receive the file pointer as an argument.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int function(FILE *infp);

int main ()
{
        FILE *infp;
        printf("\n%d\n",function(infp));
}

int function(FILE *infp)
{
        int num, counter=0;
        if ((infp = fopen ("text.txt", "r")) == NULL)
                printf ("\ncannot open the file text.txt\n");
        while ((num = getc())!=EOF)
        {
                if (num>100)
                    counter++;
        }
        fclose(infp);
        return (counter);
 }
```

It is always outputting 0. I'm thinking either getc is not the right command to use here or maybe I am formatting the text file wrong? Any help would be great

Comment: getc returns a character, not a number. See the manual of it.

Comment: `getc()` returns a `char`, which when stored as an `int` gets the ASCII value of that `char`. If you are aiming to find a number written in text inside the file, then this is way off

Comment: Look at fscanf to get a text number.

Comment: Your `infp` parameter is completely useless (and passing (therefore reading) it uninitialized actually invokes undefined behavior).  Either remove it or open and close the file in `main` and pass a valid `FILE *` pointer to your function.  How to parse your text file depends largely on what will be in the file.  Only numbers?  In what format?  can you show an example?

Comment: Start by logging what `getc` returns to see if it's what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

here you are using getc() to catch numbers from file but your getc() will give you only one character at a time so 
for example :

---

if your file content is like : "103 9";
then your  getc() will give "1" at 1st time then it will give you "0" and then "3"..
in this way you will never be reading a number completely and you are getting one character at a time.
To get rid of this you can use : fscanf(infp, "%d", &num);....
this will give you one complete number in one go. 
then you can easily match the numbers.

---

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a tad bit of work to do this in C. How about grabbing the text content. Splitting on space. Verifying the correct ASCII characters that represent a base 10 number `[48,57]` (interval notation), from there you can apply a conversion algorithm, such as `atoi`

Answer (score 0):

`getc()` reads the next *character* from a stream. What you want is to possibly tokenize the file via some delimiter (let's say space). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266357/tokenizing-strings-in-c) for more details.